# react-native-splash-screen with lottie

Tags: ios, react-native, lottie, react-native-splash-screen

I want to add a Lottie animation to the splash screen of my react-native application. However, I read something like "Apple doesn't allow anything to move in the launch view controller as far as I know." Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

The launch screen is a static image that is shown by iOS itself while your app is still loading and before it has begun executing,  which is why it can't be animated.

You can set your launch screen to be the same as the first frame of your animated launch screen and then when your app actually starts it shows the animation, but this can be tricky for a number of reasons:

- Different device resolutions may result in the launch image being scaled differently which can cause a noticeable jump as your app transitions between the launch image and your animation
- if the app has previously been run, iOS will save a screenshot of the last time the app was suspended and use that as the launch image for subsequent launches which will also result in a strange visual jump between the apps apparent previous state and your animation.

I know that splash screens are common and popular but Apple's official recommendation has always been not to have them. The intent of the launch image is just to show something briefly while the app is loading.  Splash screens with delays or animations are just getting in the way of the user actually using your app.